# Mount multiple folders from a container to one Persistent volume in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, mounted-volumes

I have the following folder structure in a container

`/usr/src/app/upload/library`

`/usr/src/app/upload/encoded-video`

`/usr/src/app/upload/profile`

`/usr/src/app/upload/thumbs`

Now I want to mount the folder `/library` to a Kubernetes PV
and `/encoded-video`, `/encoded`, `/profile` and `/thumbs` to a different Kubernetes PV. Any idea if this is possible? or should I create for every folder an PV? I tried with and without subpaths but getting a containerconfigerror with the error "Failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount" also tried more situations see below yaml

```yaml
          volumeMounts:
            - name: library
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload
              subPath: library
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload
              subPath: encoded-video
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload
              subPath: profile
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload
              subPath: thumbs
      volumes:
        - name: library
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-library
        - name: generated-media
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-generated-media
```

```yaml
          volumeMounts:
            - name: library
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/library
              subPath: library
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/encoded-video
              subPath: encoded-video
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/profile
              subPath: profile
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/thumbs
              subPath: encoded-video
      volumes:
        - name: library
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-library
        - name: generated-media
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-generated-media
```

```yaml
          volumeMounts:
            - name: library
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/library
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/encoded-video
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/profile
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/thumbs
      volumes:
        - name: library
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-library
        - name: generated-media
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-generated-media
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: library
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/library
              subPath: library
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/encoded-video
              subPath: encoded-video
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/profile
              subPath: profile
            - name: generated-media
              mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/thumbs
              subPath: thumbs
      volumes:
        - name: library
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-library
        - name: generated-media
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-generated-media
```

It's the same as your second example, but with a change in line 13, i.e. *mountPath: .../thumbs* and *subPath: thumbs*.

The last directory of your path must coincide with the subPath of the PVC.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath

Comment: Thanks, I did make a typo in the example. When I use your yaml i get the following error 
```yaml
  Warning  Failed     5s (x3 over 27s)  kubelet            Error: failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount "generated-media" of container "immich-microservice"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your issue with different situations and successfully created a pod using the below yaml.

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: library-volume
      mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/library
    - name: encoded1
      mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/encoded-video
    - name: profile1
      mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/profile
    - name: thumbs1
      mountPath: /usr/src/app/upload/thumbs
  volumes:
  - name: library-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc-library1
  - name: encoded1
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc-encoded1
  - name: profile1
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc-profile1
  - name: thumbs1
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc-thumbs1
```

Note that the persistent volume claim must exist before the pod starts running, otherwise the pod will fail to start. Check have you set `accessModes: - ReadWriteMany`.

Comment: Thanks, in you example you are using a seperate PV for each folder. My question was about how to mount multiple folders with one PV.

Comment: For multiple folders with one PV @glv answer should work as you are getting an error check container's security context is properly set to allow access to the mounted volume, Make sure that the subPath you are trying to use already exists, check logs to further debug the issue.